# Dúvidas com JSF

Tags: java, jsf, mvc

Bem, estou há pouco tempo em Java WEB e estou com algumas dúvidas em JavaServ Faces, e gostaria de entender, para conseguir manipular bem, etc. Então se alguém puder tirar minhas dúvidas, ficarei grato.

**OBS: Estou usando JSF com padrão MVC**

***1)*** Existem 2 tipos de sessões, a sessão que o DAO usa para fazer acesso ao banco de dados e a do navegador, a Sessão do navegador guarda todas as classes que está no sistema?

***Exemplo:*** Imagina que eu criei um Sistema que tenha 2 classes, sendo elas Cliente e Conta... ai tem os Getters e Setters e também criei o ControladorCliente e ControladorConta, já que a View se comunica com o Controller, e o Controller com o Model (Back-end).
Ai, entrei no site e automaticamente vai ter esses 2 objetos como variável da Sessão? Porém, nulos? Ai quando eu logar por exemplo, o Cliente da Sessão vai receber as informações da minha conta que loguei direto do controlador?

***2)*** Proteção de páginas, eu sei um pouco de PHP, entendi e consegui manipular bem, e lá existe o comando header(Location index.html); que redireciona para uma outra página, e é bastante usado com o comando isset(var), por exemplo, o cara não está logado, então não pode acessar tal página, então se tentar acessar está página protegida será redirecionado para o index.html... Já que o JSF não trabalha com códigos JAVA no código fonte como PHP, deve ter algum comando para manipular no MODELO, ai queria saber se alguém sabe este comando.

Answer (score 0):

Para você entender sobre as sessões, sugiro que você de uma estudada no **ciclo de vida do JSF**. Mas de maneira resumida, segue uma imagem para ilustrar a situação.

[image: Clico de Vida JSF]

Segue um artigo bem interessante:
https://www.devmedia.com.br/ciclo-de-vida-do-javaserver-faces-jsf/27893

De maneira bem resumida, você poderá ter para controlar os objetos de seus "Bens":

**Request Scope**: todos os objetos armazenados no escopo request, sobrevivem apenas a uma submissão ao ciclo de vida do JSF (os quais irei explicar em outro post). Com isso temos uma duração que condiz com a requisição sendo enviada ao servidor, e este devolvendo a resposta ao usuário que disparou a ação. Possui o menor tempo de vida dentre os escopos, desta forma, os objetos permanecem por pouco tempo em memória sendo esta liberada com maior frequência e com isso temos uma aplicação que tende a escalar melhor.

**Session Scope:** todos os objetos e atributos vinculados ao ManagedBean, sobreviverão durante toda a sessão do usuário. A sessão é definida pelo vinculo do navegador do usuário com o servidor. Desta forma, se usuário abrir dois navegadores, ele estará criando duas sessões com o servidor. Este escopo era muito utilizado nas versões do JSF 1.x, para se trabalhar em casos onde era necessário manter o estado de objetos, atualmente esta necessidade, muitas vezes, pode ser resolvida através do View Scope.

**Application Scope:** tudo armazenado neste escopo permanece enquanto a aplicação estiver executando e é compartilhado entre todos os usuários. É recomendado sempre que for necessário guardar informações que podem ser utilizada por diversas partes da aplicação como parâmetros e também implementar funcionalidades para prover comunicação entre usuários. Este escopo também é interessante para se trabalhar com caches manuais de valores, como exemplo lista de estados.

**View Scope:** adicionado a partir da versão JSF 2, foi criado para resolver o problema de sempre utilizar session quando era necessário manter os dados entre requisições e que não onerasse tanto a aplicação. O View Scope oferece suporte ao modelo statefull do framework, onde é possível manter os dados durante quantas requisições forem necessárias, desde que todas estas sejam realizadas para a mesma view. Caso seja executado uma requisição para uma pagina e/ou ManagedBean diferente, o escopo é limpo, evitando assim que objetos não utilizados se mantenham vivos por muito tempo (caso que ocorria no escopo sessão).

---